# How to remove repetitions using retract in this particular situation?

Tags: database, prolog, prolog-setof

```
    %Examples:
    %days([saturday,sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday]).
    %slots([1,2,3,4,5]).
    %course_meetings(csen402,tutorial,t07,nehal,'tutorial for t07').
    %course_meetings(comm401,lecture,all_group_4,dr_amr_talaat,'lecture 1')
%tutorialrooms([c6301,b4108,c2201,c2301,c2202,c2203]).



        day_tut(Day,Slot,Place,Course,Group,Instructor,Descr):-
            days(X),member(Day,X),
            tutorialrooms(X1),member(Place,X1),
            course_meetings(Course,tutorial,Group,Instructor,Descr),
            slots(X2),member(Slot,X2),
            assert(day(Day,Slot,tutorial,Place,Course,Group,Instructor,Descr)).
```

I would like to find a way to remove certain facts after asserting for example 
every (day) fact has to have  only one room for each day and slot
example: we can have `day(sat,1,_,c6301,_,_,_,_)` and
                     `day(sat,1,_,c6302,_,_,_,_)` but we can't  have 
another occurrence of `day(sat,1,_,c6301,_,_,_,_)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to remove redundant solutions of a `Goal` – this is what you probably mean with removing repetitions – simply replace `Goal` by `setof(t,Goal,_)`.  This works as long as there are only ground solutions for `Goal` and as long as `Goal` terminates universally. Thus, there is no need for any data base manipulation to remove redundant solutions.

```
?- member(X, [a,b,a,c]).
   X = a
;  X = b
;  X = a  % redundant!
;  X = c.
?- setof(t,member(X, [a,b,a,c]),_).
   X = a
;  X = b
;  X = c.
```